# How to create custom methods for use in spring security expression language annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I would like to create a class that adds custom methods for use in spring security expression language for method-based authorization via annotations.

For example, I would like to create a custom method like 'customMethodReturningBoolean' to be used somehow like this:

```
  @PreAuthorize("customMethodReturningBoolean()")
  public void myMethodToSecure() { 
    // whatever
  }
```

My question is this.
If it is possible, what class should I subclass to create my custom methods, how would I go about configuring it in the spring xml configuration files and come someone give me an example of a custom method used in this way?

Comment: I don't have time to type an answer right now but I followed this guide and it worked brilliantly: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-create-new-custom-security-expression  I'm using Spring Security 5.1.1.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You'll need to subclass two classes.

First, set a new method expression handler

```
<global-method-security>
  <expression-handler ref="myMethodSecurityExpressionHandler"/>
</global-method-security>
```

`myMethodSecurityExpressionHandler` will be a subclass of `DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler` which overrides `createEvaluationContext()`, setting a subclass of `MethodSecurityExpressionRoot` on the `MethodSecurityEvaluationContext`.

For example:

```
@Override
public EvaluationContext createEvaluationContext(Authentication auth, MethodInvocation mi) {
    MethodSecurityEvaluationContext ctx = new MethodSecurityEvaluationContext(auth, mi, parameterNameDiscoverer);
    MethodSecurityExpressionRoot root = new MyMethodSecurityExpressionRoot(auth);
    root.setTrustResolver(trustResolver);
    root.setPermissionEvaluator(permissionEvaluator);
    root.setRoleHierarchy(roleHierarchy);
    ctx.setRootObject(root);

    return ctx;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, sounds like a good idea, but all of the properties of *DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler* are private without accessors, so I was curious how you extended the class without any ugly reflection. Thanks.

Comment: You mean trustResolver, etc?   Those all have setters in DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler (at least in Spring Security 3.0)  See: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/expression/method/DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler.html

Comment: @ericacm How do you get around `MethodSecurityExpressionRoot` being *package-private*?

Answer (score 186):

None of the mentioned techniques will work anymore. It seems as though Spring has gone through great lengths to prevent users from overriding the SecurityExpressionRoot.

EDIT 11/19/14 Setup Spring to use security annotations:

```
<beans ... xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" ... >
...
<sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
```

Create a bean like this:

```
@Component("mySecurityService")
public class MySecurityService {
    public boolean hasPermission(String key) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then do something like this in your jsp:

```
<sec:authorize access="@mySecurityService.hasPermission('special')">
    <input type="button" value="Special Button" />
</sec:authorize>
```

Or annotate a method:

```
@PreAuthorize("@mySecurityService.hasPermission('special')")
public void doSpecialStuff() { ... }
```

Additionally, you may use [Spring Expression Language](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) in your `@PreAuthorize` annotations to access the current authentication as well as method arguments.

For example:

```
@Component("mySecurityService")
public class MySecurityService {
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, String foo) { ... }
}
```

Then update your `@PreAuthorize` to match the new method signature:

```
@PreAuthorize("@mySecurityService.hasPermission(authentication, #foo)")
public void doSpecialStuff(String foo) { ... }
```

Comment: Any way to give MySecurityService a handle on an existing `Authentication` object?

Comment: @Bosh in your hasPermission method, you can use `Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();` to get the current authentication token.

Comment: Thanks James for your answer. Do I have to define mySecurityService in spring config file?

Comment: And is @PreAuthorize a custom annotation?

Comment: You don't need to define mySecurityService in any XML file if you have a component-scan setup for the package that the service is in. If you don't have a matching component-scan, then you must use an xml bean definition.

@PreAuthorize comes from org.springframework.security

Comment: James, simply great bro !!  But id doesn't worked for me.  I created a bean as component and trying to use in PreAuthorize via my component class.

Comment: You may need to specify the name of the bean to the annotation like this: @Component("mySecurityService") or use the @Named annotation.

Comment: @James Watkins : I have used `@PreAuthorize` example shown above but hasPermission method of MySecurityService is not getting called. In xml I have defined global security pre-post annotation enabled as well. Code is something like : @RequestMapping...then @PreAuthorize...then method. Method is working fine but  @PreAuthorize is having no impact.

Comment: @VJS Please see the edit I made. You will need to configure spring to use these annotations. I'm surprised nobody else complained about this important missing detail :)

Comment: @James Watkins : Yes, I googled it and found solution. But thanks for your effort. This solution is very clean and easy to understand. It saved my lot of time.

Comment: @James Watkins : 

I am getting : 

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:  No bean named 'mySecurityService' is defined

Comment: Incredibly simple and straightforward solution! You saved me a lot of time and for that I thank you!

Comment: Spent a while trying to get the custom expression root gunk to work. Your solution is far simpler to get to work thanks.

Comment: Is there any way I can make 'authentication' argument implicit?

Comment: @DhananjayK You may remove the argument and fetch the Authentication object statically. Caution: I'm not sure how this works if you are forking threads: Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

Comment: @James Watkins Can I use mySecurityService on JSPs to hide or show links?

Comment: @GD_Java Yes, using the spring security taglib https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/taglibs.html

Comment: @James Watkins I wrote a component as you suggested and calling it from JSP like this <sec:authorize access="@permisssionEvaluator.hasPermiss‌​ion('testPermi', ${session})">. But it is not worming any more. The only difference is my hasPermission accept one more object which is session.

Answer (score 15):

Thanks [ericacm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/158658/ericacm), but it does not work for a few reasons:

- The properties of *DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler* are private (reflection visibility kludges undesirable)
- At least in my Eclipse, I can't resolve a *MethodSecurityEvaluationContext* object

The differences are that we call the existing [createEvaluationContext](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/expression/method/MethodSecurityExpressionHandler.html#createEvaluationContext%28org.springframework.security.core.Authentication,%20org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInvocation%29) method and then add our custom root object. Finally I just returned an [StandardEvaluationContext](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/expression/SecurityExpressionRoot.html) object type since MethodSecurityEvaluationContext would not resolve in the compiler (they are both from the same interface). This is the code that I now have in production.

Make *[MethodSecurityExpressionHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/expression/method/MethodSecurityExpressionHandler.html)* use our custom root:

```
public class CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler extends DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler  {

    // parent constructor
    public CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * Custom override to use {@link CustomSecurityExpressionRoot}
     * 
     * Uses a {@link MethodSecurityEvaluationContext} as the <tt>EvaluationContext</tt> implementation and
     * configures it with a {@link MethodSecurityExpressionRoot} instance as the expression root object.
     */
    @Override
    public EvaluationContext createEvaluationContext(Authentication auth, MethodInvocation mi) {
        // due to private methods, call original method, then override it's root with ours
        StandardEvaluationContext ctx = (StandardEvaluationContext) super.createEvaluationContext(auth, mi);
        ctx.setRootObject( new CustomSecurityExpressionRoot(auth) );
        return ctx;
    }
}
```

This replaces the default root by extending [SecurityExpressionRoot](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/expression/SecurityExpressionRoot.html). Here I've renamed hasRole to hasEntitlement:

```
public class CustomSecurityExpressionRoot extends SecurityExpressionRoot  {

    // parent constructor
    public CustomSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication a) {
        super(a);
    }

    /**
     * Pass through to hasRole preserving Entitlement method naming convention
     * @param expression
     * @return boolean
     */
    public boolean hasEntitlement(String expression) {
        return hasRole(expression);
    }

}
```

Finally update securityContext.xml (and make sure it's referenced from your applcationContext.xml):

```
<!-- setup method level security using annotations -->
<security:global-method-security
        jsr250-annotations="disabled"
        secured-annotations="disabled"
        pre-post-annotations="enabled">
    <security:expression-handler ref="expressionHandler"/>
</security:global-method-security>

<!--<bean id="expressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">-->
<bean id="expressionHandler" class="com.yourSite.security.CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler" />
```

**Note:** the @Secured annotation will not accept this override as it runs through a different validation handler. So, in the above xml I disabled them to prevent later confusion.

Comment: thanks. great help for me but by the new changes in spring security, you can not override _createEvaluationContext_ but you have to override _createEvaluationContextInternal_ and also _createSecurityExpressionRoot_.