# Method security in Spring Security

Tags: spring-security

I have a question regarding using  Spring Security to protect against SQL injection. First of all, I know that use prepared statement can protect from any SQL injection. But In my project I want to show that use Spring Security could help to protect or mitigate against this kind of attack. what i did so far, i made connection using JDBC & Spring and I applied Spring Security and every thing is fine. My question is in my project i used two ways to protect against SQL injection. The first one is Santizing user input and the second one is using Spring Security. I could pass malicious input through Sanitizaing and I want to show that the role of spring security. for example, I pass this input:

```
TV' UNION SELECT credit_no From credit;--
```

In this case how I can tell Spring security that it doesnot give any users the credit number. By the way, I used method security level. Just I want to give me an easy way to analyze the user input to see If it has access to data which he asked such as credit.

I hope that clear

Answer (score 0):

Well, your question is not 100% clear, and it may vary on your architecture, but [pre post annotations](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#el-pre-post-annotations) can work well to grab user input. 
You can create your own [permission evaluator](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#el-method-built-in) and check permission for pre authorization in your methods.

```
@PostFilter("hasPermission(filterObject, 'customoperation')")
public CreditCard getCreditCard(String userInput) {
    //
}
```

and your `hasPermission` method (that you've read about in the link above) goes something like:

```
public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication,
        Object target, Object permission) {
    if ("customoperation".equals(permission)) {
        //your logic here, returning true or false, filtering the object
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can also extend the expression handler to use custom functions. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632982/how-to-create-custom-methods-for-use-in-spring-security-expression-language-annot/6634438#6634438).

Comment: Thank you for answer, and what about the applicationContext.xml. How I can make configration in it.

Comment: well that's a very general question. you should look at the documentation. And there's a lot of questions here about it. You can search. Don't forget to vote the good questions and accept yours. Read que faq.