# Calling static methods from Spring Security Expressions?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-el

I'm looking for a way to extend Spring Security Expressions to support an existing security infrastructure.  I'm aware you can extend the MethodSecurityExpressionRoot as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632982/how-to-create-custom-methods-for-use-in-spring-security-expression-language-annot/6634438#6634438), but I also found [reference](http://%20You%20can%20also%20add%20functionality%20by%20calling%20static%20methods%20directly%20through%20Spring%20EL,%20rather%20than%20adding%20things%20to%20the%20root%20object.) to directly calling static methods through Spring Expression Language (Spring EL or SpEL).  Unfortunately the [official page](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/expressions.html) on Spring Expression methods doesn't directly describe how to do this.

How can I invoke a static method through Spring Expression methods?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

By using the [`T(fully.qualified.name).methodName()` syntax](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-types):

> You can use the special `T` operator to specify an instance of `java.lang.Class` (the type). Static methods are invoked by using this operator as well. The `StandardEvaluationContext` uses a `TypeLocator` to find types, and the `StandardTypeLocator` (which can be replaced) is built with an understanding of the `java.lang` package. This means that `T()` references to types within `java.lang` do not need to be fully qualified, but all other type references must be.

The `T` element returns a reference to the type instead of an instance. For example, the equivalent of `Collections.singleton("Hello")` is

```
T(java.util.Collections).singleton('Hello')
```

Comment: How can I pass method argument's property as one of target method's parameter?

Comment: @JinKwon `T(java.util.Collections).singleton(#yourArg)`