# Enum with method used in a query is not converted

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I use spring boot with spring data jpa

I have a field with a integer data type.
I have an enum with different value for this field

```
public class Operation{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "operation_Sequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "operation_Sequence", sequenceName = "operation_Sequence", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    private Integer eventProcessStatus;
}

public enum EventProcessStatus {
    CLOSE(2),
    OPEN(99);

    private final int id;

    EventProcessStatus(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

In my repository, I search to use this enum with the getId method

```
@Query(value = "select ce from Operation ce where "
            + "(ce.eventProcessStatus=com.ns.perma.domain.constants.EventProcessStatus.CLOSE.getId() )")
public List<Operation> findAllOperation();
```

When this query is executed, I get CLOSE: INVALID IDENTIFIER.

In the sql log I see

...

```
where
operation0_.event_process_status=com.ns.perma.billing.domain.constants.EventProcessStatus.SUCCESS.getId()
```

So the command is not converted.

Any idea?

Comment: Can't you change the type of `eventProcessStatus` in `Operation` to `EventProcessStatus` via a custom `javax.persistence.AttributeConverter`, or even simply with `javax.persistence.Enumerated` if you're happy for it to be ordinal/string based?

Comment: Can you add Operation class also ?

Comment: You mean you cannot modify the class `Operation`?

Comment: how the query will need to be modified if i use a converter

Answer (score 2):

You can't use arbitrary Java snippets in a JPQL query.

But you may use [SpEL expressions in a query annotation](https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions).
Just take note that you need to use the [special `T` operator to access static members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585627/calling-static-methods-from-spring-security-expressions). Therefore the following (or something similar to it) should work:

```
@Query(value = "select ce from Operation ce where "
            + "ce.eventProcessStatus
= :#{ T(com.ns.perma.domain.constants.EventProcessStatus).CLOSE.id ")
public List<Operation> findAllOperation();
```

Comment: that compile but faile at runtime

Answer (score 1):

@JensSchauder is right. You can try this way also.

You can use enum value as parameter and pass in the query

```
@Query(value = "select ce from Operation ce where ce.eventProcessStatus= ?1")
public List<Operation> findAllOperation(int enumValue);
```

Then call this function using enum value

```
operationRepo.findAllOperation(EventProcessStatus.CLOSE.getId());
```