# spring security - how to configure ExpressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice to use a custom expression handler?

Tags: spring, security, spring-security, spring-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create custom methods for use in spring security expression language annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632982/how-to-create-custom-methods-for-use-in-spring-security-expression-language-anno)

I wish to use custom methods inside `@PreAuthorize` like :

```
@PreAuthorize("canPlayGolf(something,something)")
```

For that, I created a replica of `MethodSecurityExpressionRoot` (can't subclass it as it has package access in **Spring Security 3.0.6**) and add my custom functions there. I need to use this custom expression root in `MethodSecurityExpressionHandler`, but since it hardcodes `MethodSecurityExpressionRoot`, I subclassed it to use my custom expression root (I had to create a replica of `MethodSecurityEvaluationContext` too as I had to use it in my override of `createEvaluationContext` and it had again package access).

Finally, I can't figure out how to wire my custom expression handler in `ExpressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice`, so that I can use my custom expressions in `@PreAuthorize`

Comment: I found the solution here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632982/how-to-create-custom-methods-for-use-in-spring-security-expression-language-anno