# Extending SpEL with own methods in Grails?

Tags: grails, spring-security, spring-el

I'd like to add custom SpEL methods in Grails applciation, like it's done for plain Spring-Security application in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632982/how-to-create-custom-methods-for-use-in-spring-security-expression-language-anno), by overriding [EvaluationContext](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html). Will this work?

How do I plug `global-method-security` into security config? I can [configure security](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/22%20Miscellaneous%20Properties.html), but what to add there? Something like

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity = {
    'global-method-security' {
        'expression-handler' {
            ref("myMethodSecurityExpressionHandler")
        }
    }
}
```

? But what code will interpret it?

Looking into `SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin.groovy` also gives me no insights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only available if you also have the spring-security-acl plugin installed. It configures the `expressionHandler` bean:

```
expressionHandler(DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler) {
   parameterNameDiscoverer = ref('parameterNameDiscoverer')
   permissionEvaluator = ref('permissionEvaluator')
   roleHierarchy = ref('roleHierarchy')
   trustResolver = ref('authenticationTrustResolver')
}
```

So if you have your own subclass of `DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler` you can replace the bean in `resources.groovy` like this:

```
import com.mycompany.myapp.MyMethodSecurityExpressionHandler

beans = {
   expressionHandler(MyMethodSecurityExpressionHandler) {
      parameterNameDiscoverer = ref('parameterNameDiscoverer')
      permissionEvaluator = ref('permissionEvaluator')
      roleHierarchy = ref('roleHierarchy')
      trustResolver = ref('authenticationTrustResolver')
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The ACL plugin does it, but my  `expressionHandler` neveer gets invoked. App's `resources.groovy` is executed before plugin's `configureExpressionBeans()/doWithSpring()` - so probably my `expressionHandler` is overridden by ACL's. Looking into a way to fix it.

Comment: Didn't manage to make it pick up my `expressionHandler` - apparently ACL's is instantiated. What can I do?

Comment: @VictorSergienko: Any success? I am in the same situation.

Comment: Sadly not, it never worked for me due to that `expressionHandler` problem.