# Hiding information for a particular user

Tags: java, spring

I am using RESTFUL webservices using Spring framework.Some information is displayed on the user interface using the data returned by webservices. There is a webservice, which gets the usernames and their roles from the database. For a particular user , I would like to have all the webservices display data in the form of `####,####` for first name,lastname ; `##/##/####` for date of birth etc. Since I am using JDBC to connect to the database, here's what I was thinking of doing:

Should I consider passing an additional parameter (maybe sending a value `0` or `1` ; `0` for all other users and `1` for user for which I want to hide the information) to each and every `GET` webservice so that when it comes to getting data from the database in the JDBC code part,I could check whether the flag is set to `1` or `0` and based on this, I could do something like this in the JDBC code :

```
// Code for a case when flag is set to `0`. Hence retrieving information from the database.

    while(rs.next()) {

                    EmployeeList    empList  = new EmployeeList();
                    empList.setEmpId(empId);
                    empList.setEmployeeName(rs.getString("name"));
                    employeeList.add(empList);

                }

// Code for a case when flag is set to `1`. Hence hiding information and not retrieving information from the database.

 while(rs.next()) {

                    EmployeeList    empList  = new EmployeeList();
                    empList.setEmpId(empId);
                    empList.setEmployeeName("####,######");
                    employeeList.add(empList);

                }
```

I am wondering, if this is an appropriate way to achieve my task or is there some other way around?

**Edit:More clarifications on my requirements:**

I am using jqxWidget in the UI to display the information I am getting from a RESTFUL webservice in JSON format. For example, let's consider [this example](https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxgrid/jquery-grid-getting-started.htm) and the screenshot for better understanding of my requirement:

[image]

1) Let's say I am getting all the information from the JSON response which I am populating in the jQXWidget as shown in the screenshot above.

2) In the above widget, I would like to hide say for example, First Name, Last Name and Quantity like the following:

```
First Name = XXXXX
Last Name  = XXXXX
Quantity   = ####
```

In my application, if a user clicks on a particular row , a new page is displayed with some additional information. After click, new sets of web services are called and those web services takes `First Name`, `Last Name` and `Quantity` as input parameters. My concern is that, if I somehow replace the `First Name` with `XXXXX`, `Last Name` with `XXXXX` and `Quantity` with `####` using any approach, when a user clicks on any of the row of the widget, the next set of web services
are going to get `XXXX` and `####` as input and eventually will fail. Please correct me if my understanding until this point is not correct. 
Thanks

I am using Spring 4.2.5 version.

Comment: You are describing profiing/granting. You should represent the functionalities as grants and assign them (or not) to the users.

Comment: @NiVeR I didn't quite understand. Could you elaborate please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what sort of information hiding you want to achieve. Typically you shouldn't do this manually.

You can use, for example, role-based authorization. Exact details depends on the web-service framework you are using.

For spring MVC, you can use something similar to this:

[Custom authorization in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13766685/custom-authorization-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my post to clarify what information I am trying to hide. Could you please take a look and see if the Spring based approach is still a good idea to use? Thanks