# Pass variable to annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, authorization

I'm using Spring Security and `@PreAuthorize` to secure methods. I want to do something like:

Controller:

```
@PreAuthorize(SampleStaticClass.STATIC_FINAL_FIELD)
void someMethod() {}
```

Service:

```
// SampleStaticClass
public static final String STATIC_FINAL_FIELD = someService().getThisFieldFromDatabase();
```

but this requires constant expression. Any solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

You can either (a) add mapping between hardcoded values and stored in DB or (b) take solution from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632982/how-to-create-custom-methods-for-use-in-spring-security-expression-language-anno):

```
@PreAuthorize("@mySecurityService.hasCustomPermission()")
some method() {}
```

Of course I prefer the first one as it is simpler to implement and support.