# @PreAuthorize not working

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-security

Regarding [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14904130/840184), I have tried the same and for JSP part it is working fine. 
I have used @PreAuthorize annotation on controller and tried it on service layer as well but hasPermission method of MySecurityService is not getting called.

I have added global method security pre post enabled as well in my spring-security-context.xml.

Please help.

Comment: The annotations will only work if they are on components in the same contexts as you have defined the `global-method-security` in. If that is in the `ContextLoaderListener` and your components live in the `DispatcherServlet` it isn't going to work. The same applies for all other AOP related options (transactions, scheduling etc.).

Comment: yes. thanks. I have written global-method-security in servlet-context.xml and now its working fine.