# Why is Spring-Security 4.x MethodSecurityExpressionRoot package scoped?

Tags: spring, spring-security

`/**
 * Extended expression root object which contains extra method-specific functionality.
 *
 * @author Luke Taylor
 * @since 3.0
 */
class MethodSecurityExpressionRoot extends SecurityExpressionRoot implements
        MethodSecurityExpressionOperations {`

Why is the MethodSecurityExpressionRoot package scoped? Can't I extend this class?

Comment: The author probably didn't see any purpose of extending it. Do you?

Comment: holmis83, I have a bit more complex authorization checks. Something very similar to what they are discussing here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632982/how-to-create-custom-methods-for-use-in-spring-security-expression-language-anno .               I need roles, authorities/operations/permission, in addition to other credential details like that can be from a request to be validated against.

Comment: I think I might implement what "James Watkins" says in that thread. I also need to research how I may be able to pass other details to the method execution. OR, I will use the SecurityContextHolder per one of the suggestion.