# How to modify hasIpAddress to validate X-Forwarded-For?

Tags: spring-security

I would like to know, how can I modify the `hasIpAddress` method in the Spring Security, so that it verify the X-Forwarded-For header in the request, instead of remote ip address?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create custom methods for use in spring security expression language annotations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632982/how-to-create-custom-methods-for-use-in-spring-security-expression-language-anno)

Answer (score 1):

You can choose to create a custom class with the logic that you want. Then, maybe extend `DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler` and override `createEvaluationContextInternal` where you can instantiate your custom class and set it as a variable in the `StandardEvaluationContext`. See [OAuth2WebSecurityExpressionHandler](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/expression/OAuth2WebSecurityExpressionHandler.java) to see how spring-security-oauth2 extended `DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler` to add oauth2-specific validation logic for example. Then in your http security rule, set the expression handler to use your custom expression handler. In xml, this would look something like:

```
<security:http>
        <security:expression-handler ref="yourCustomExpressionHandler"/>
</security:http>
```